# Google app engine or do i need Google apps script?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I use Google business some of the apps interact with gmail.
When you open a email under in the footer of that email you get a
information box of the app, then it can get data of that email and 
put it in a system..

Start mail.google.com --> get email and open --> go to the box under the email --> do something in the box with the data of that email..

How to build the same app functions but for our self, doe i need Google app engine  or do i need Google apps script. Some links would be helpful

gr.

Comment: Apps script is an excellent tool for building end user tools. With apps script you can access your gmail. App engine is for building scalable web applications.

Comment: hi, well it still doesn't answer my question.. what do i need to get a app in gmail in the email what i just open.. i need to interact with our back end server.. 
i wanna put a button under the email --> i push --> it send the email address to our server..
but how do i get this button in there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to write a gmail contextual gadget. You can do it with appengine or any other provider. You dont need to use the gmail api since the contextual gadget already gives you all the necessary data (except attachments).
The other answer says you need to use oauth scopes to access the mail which is incorrect. You can publish the app anywhere you want including the marketplace. See: 
 https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets

Comment: thx that's the one..

but it's strange you have to learn a lot 1.https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/gs?hl=nl&csw=1
2.https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets?hl=nl&csw=1#extractor  
3.https://developers.google.com/google-apps/extensions-console/?hl=nl&csw=1

Comment: https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/enterprise-deep-dive-gmail-contextual-gadgets.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine is just a host for web applications and has nothing to do with access to Gmail.

In order to access Gmail data, you may want to create a [Google Apps Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/) App.
You will have do decide what data you want from the email, and ask for the user to approve the correct [OAuth2 scopes](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Answer (score 0):

As Zig mentioned Gmail Contextual Gadgets are one way, but I'd recommend evaluating [Actions in the Inbox](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/). It can provide a better user experience over gadgets from both visibility and performance. It does require that you [register with Google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/registering-with-google) but you can start development today.

Comment: actions in the inbox.. is only one button that you can have.. and that's something you wanna send to other people not for your own use...